# Access Android Paths from Codename one?

Tags: android, file, codenameone, gallery, native

I am trying to make a snippet of code that I can open file returned from native code , but if I use 
`FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(file)`
 it always returns false even though that I just returned the path from the native code

my code returned the path like this :

`String path =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() +"/"+param+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";`

if you check you can find it in the gallery , but when returned to codename one it doesn't see the file

any suggestions

---------------- Update :

I am call the native like this but it seems it doesn't wait for the call to finish

```
final StatusClass imagePath = new StatusClass();    
Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.p("hello native");
                    imagePath.setStatusMsg(AccessNativeCamera.capturePhoto("Test"));

                Log.p("goodbye native");
                Log.p("imagePath "+imagePath);
            }
        });

        if(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists("file://" + imagePath.getStatusMsg())){
            Dialog.show("Check ","File exists", null, null);
        }
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists("file://" + file)
```

Paths in Codename One are always absolute and should use URL notation.

Comment: The API is probably asynchronous which is a different question. Notice that Android API's need to run on the Android EDT https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-use-native-edt.html

Comment: thank you but I managed to solve my problem with adding a little bit of delay in order to check that the file is already there or not

Comment: I am trying to do `Image.createImage(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream("NativePathRetunred from iOS")));`
Native Path from IOS is in this form :
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XX-XXXX-XXXXXX/Documents/IMG_0331.JPG` , but the image is not created successfully even though the path is correct and the image is saved in the photo library

Comment: I even tried to do `Display.getInstance().execute("NativePathReturned from iOS")` and it didn't open the image

Comment: Where did you get that path from? Apps are isolated on mobile devices and don't have access to all paths

Comment: from the native I implemented the camera capture [ and from the function didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo I get the path ]

Comment: The path you got there probably needs to be converted to a documents path